# Java JTabbedPane Add New Tab

Tags: java, swing

I want to create a `JTabbedPane` where the tab furthest to the right is always a special tab with just a '+' character, and whenever you click that a new tab is inserted right before it, with a specific gui attached to it (premade). I have a class that extends `JPanel`, and I want that to be the class that fills up the new tab when the special tab is clicked. What's the best way to do this? Thanks!

Comment: It's possible, but, you'll need to write a new UI delegate for it, as this is what controls the laying out of the tabs

Comment: Of course you do some googling and you might find something like [jhrome](https://github.com/jedwards1211/Jhrome)

Comment: Jhrome looks promising but it has a lot of features I don't really want. It'll take some playing around to figure it out, but it seems like the best option. Thanks!